# PL/SQL - Update multiple rows in the target table from one row in the source table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-merge

I'm using a merge statement to merge two tables where one row in the source table may update multiple rows in the target table.

It goes a bit like this

```
MERGE TABLE1 A
USING (SELECT EMP_CODE, DAYS_OFF FROM TABLE2) B
ON (A.ID = B.EMP_CODE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET A.DAYS_OFF = B.DAYS_OFF;
```

However, when i attempt this, i get `SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables`

Is there any other way i can do this?

Comment: Show us your complete stored procedure

Comment: @jWeaver i'm facing a different problem than the one in the post you mentioned. My problem is that i can't make sure the ON (A.ID = B.EMP_CODE) returns only one row.

Comment: would you be able to share sample data from your both table ?

Comment: @jWeaver I understand how this may seem uncooperative of me, but i really can't. Is there any other way i can help clarify the problem?

Comment: @jWeaver I've tried the first solution proposed in the post you mentioned but now it throws "SQL Error: ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table"

Comment: Could you paste your table structure ?

Comment: Table2 contains more than 1 rows for the same emp_id - for example: (emp_code=20, days_off=30) and (emp_code=20, days_off=70). And Oracle doesn't know which one `days_off` value should choose to update records with id=20 in table1 - 30 or maybe 70 ?

Comment: @jWeaver It doesn't contain any primary keys :(

Comment: doesn't matter at least show your table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i get SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the
>   source tables

Because, your source table probably contains duplicate values.

You probably need to add one more column to uniquely identify each row.

```
CREATE TABLE source_table (
    col1 NUMBER,
    col2 VARCHAR2(10),
    col3 VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO source_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 'a', 'w');
INSERT INTO source_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 'b', 'x');
INSERT INTO source_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (2, 'c', 'y');
INSERT INTO source_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (3, 'c', 'z');

COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE target_table (
    col1 NUMBER,
    col2 VARCHAR2(10),
    col3 VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO target_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 'b', 'z');
INSERT INTO target_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (3, 'd', 'w');

COMMIT;
```

Now we are going to merge two table.

```
MERGE INTO target_table trg
USING (--Actually we can simply write source_table for this example but I want to write Select:)
       SELECT col1, col2, col3
       FROM source_table 
      ) src 
ON (trg.col1 = src.col1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET --Don't forget you cannot update columns that included in ON clause
    trg.col2 = src.col2,
    trg.col3 = src.col3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    (
        col1,
        col2,
        col3
    )
    VALUES
    (
        src.col1,
        src.col2,
        src.col3
    );

COMMIT;
```

**Solution**

```
MERGE INTO target_table trg
USING source_table src --Now I simply write the table name:)
ON (
    trg.col1 = src.col1 AND
    trg.col2 = src.col2
   )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET --Don't forget you cannot update columns that included in ON clause
    trg.col3 = src.col3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    (
        col1,
        col2,
        col3
    )
    VALUES
    (
        src.col1,
        src.col2,
        src.col3
    );

COMMIT;
```

[Read more](https://aykutakin.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables/)

Answer (score 1):

That error means Oracle cannot get for each record in A,a set of records that only match to this one (f. ex. a set of records that leads to a many-to-many relationship).

What you need to do is to check in target table for duplicated items with the same "ID"

```
SQL> list                
  1  MERGE INTO  TABLE1 A
  2   USING (SELECT * FROM TABLE2) B
  3   ON (A.ID = B.EMP_CODE)
  4   WHEN MATCHED THEN
  5  UPDATE SET A.DAYS_OFF = B.DAYS_OFF
  6*
SQL> r
  1  MERGE INTO  TABLE1 A
  2   USING (SELECT * FROM TABLE2) B
  3   ON (A.ID = B.EMP_CODE)
  4   WHEN MATCHED THEN
  5  UPDATE SET A.DAYS_OFF = B.DAYS_OFF
  6*
MERGE INTO  TABLE1 A
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

SQL> select id, count(0) from table1 group by id;

        ID   COUNT(0)
---------- ----------
         1          2

SQL> delete from table1 t1 where t1.rowid not in (select max(rowid) from table1 t2 where t2.id = t1.id);

1 row deleted.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> MERGE INTO  TABLE1 A
 USING (SELECT * FROM TABLE2) B
 ON (A.ID = B.EMP_CODE)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET A.DAYS_OFF = B.DAYS_OFF  2    3    4    5  ; 

2 rows merged.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```